# AWS Lambda C# - Accessing custom context

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have a simple Lambda function written in .NET Core (C#) that uses the `APIGatewayProxyRequest` object to go through all the request properties.

If I test this lambda function (from AWS Lambda), and pass it a sample event config that contains basic information:

[image]

I can get this information like so:

```
public string FunctionHandler(APIGatewayProxyRequest request, ILambdaContext context)
        logger.Logger.Log($"Body: {request.Body}  \n");
        logger.Logger.Log($"Path: {request.Path}  \n");
        logger.Logger.Log($"Resource: {request.Resource}  \n");
```

How is it that I can access custom context or authorizer values from the same data:

[image]

I have tried:

```
logger.Logger.Log($"RequestContext Authorizor: {request.RequestContext.Authorizer}  \n");
```

Including it's different properties (`StringKey`, `PrincipleId` etc.)

It seems from Node.js, this would be simply achieved by using this:

```
event.requestContext.authorizer.customKey
```

There is no such thing in C#?

Comment: Hmm thats very odd, yeah so in nodeJS I simply do. event.requestContext.authorizer - you do realise it's a lower case 'a' right - authorizer?

Comment: Yep, I do understand that, when working with node. When working with the APIGatewayProxyRequest object, it's upper case as per the namespace and object properties. Seems there is a very different way of accessing three based off the language used. Still can't find the way through C#

Comment: Did you see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43205120/custom-authorizer-data-with-amazon-lambda-aspnetcoreserver - just spitballing here, can you turn the requestContext into a string a log it out?

Comment: Yeah, seen that and already logged a comment in the project. I'd ideally not like to use a "temp" and self declared "dirty" way of getting these. I don't see why you can get this for node with simple ease but not though . Net core C#

Comment: Yeah it does seem odd, but there are few bits like that on the AWS stack, for example there's some stuff missing from Cognito Identity pools currently that I'd imagine is coming. Sorry I couldn't be of more help - only worked with JS on Lambda!

Comment: As to your suggesting of changing request Context into a string, I've tried that but as it's an object there is no string equivalent that would display much useful... Each property off the object can be used and displayed but have no data

Comment: No worries, thanks for trying - hopefully someone else can shed some light... I'm also waiting on feedback from AWS direct, who also seem to be at a loss :)

Comment: Grab a developer support package, they're a bit slow but usually sort it out!

Comment: Thanks for this question being the best documentation on c# api gateway lambdas I can find so far!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So, after spending 3 days troubleshooting this and with the help of the AWS engineers, this is what I've found;

- There is a limitation with accessing the `$context`, `$authorizer` or any other `custom variables` from a Lambda function, written through .Net Core in `C#`

**A new service request is being created for the AWS team for this.**

To explain:

Currently, in node.js you have access to the entire payload of data being passed through to the Lambda function (within the `event` parameter), which includes all custom variables (you could access it directly - for the question example, like this: `event.requestContext.authorizer.customKey`.

This is not the same for the C# equivalent - which uses the [APIGatewayProxyRequest](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-dotnet/blob/master/Libraries/src/Amazon.Lambda.APIGatewayEvents/APIGatewayProxyRequest.cs) request object within a Lambda function. So although you have access to the entire payload (including all the custom variables) within node, within C#, you only have access to the [APIGatewayProxyRequest](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-dotnet/blob/master/Libraries/src/Amazon.Lambda.APIGatewayEvents/APIGatewayProxyRequest.cs) object. Properties of which can be found [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-dotnet/blob/master/Libraries/src/Amazon.Lambda.APIGatewayEvents/APIGatewayProxyRequest.cs):

Or in short:

```
public string Body { get; set; }
public IDictionary<string, string> Headers { get; set; }
public string HttpMethod { get; set; }
public bool IsBase64Encoded { get; set; }
public string Path { get; set; }
public IDictionary<string, string> PathParameters { get; set; }
public IDictionary<string, string> QueryStringParameters { get; set; }
public ProxyRequestContext RequestContext { get; set; }
public string Resource { get; set; }
public IDictionary<string, string> StageVariables { get; set; }
```

Being based off an object, this will not allow access to custom or "unknown" properties, even though they are part of the payload.

Long story short, as of right now: if you wish you work with custom variables of any sort, you would either need to code it through node(event) / python, or possibly overwrite an existing property within the [APIGatewayProxyRequest](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-dotnet/blob/master/Libraries/src/Amazon.Lambda.APIGatewayEvents/APIGatewayProxyRequest.cs) object.

**UPDATE:**

There is a work around to accessing the entire payload of the data coming in:

> A work around till then is have your Lambda function take in a System.IO.Stream instead of APIGatewayProxyRequest. Then you have access to the original JSON which you can parse yourself. You can grab the information you need from that JSON and then deserialize JSON to APIGatewayProxyRequest as well.

Comment: Nice to know, thats amazing that it actually doesn't work! Good job on the update.

Comment: Same problem with Java :(

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if people are wondering about this even today (after almost 3 years - I was), I have figured out a way. Could be helpful.

Note: This is only for a lambda built using the DotNet SDK.

In the AWS API G/W mapping template, you need to create a JSON template which matches the [ApiGatewayProxyRequest class](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-dotnet/blob/master/Libraries/src/Amazon.Lambda.APIGatewayEvents/APIGatewayProxyRequest.cs) so that it can be deserialized. In the example below, I am trying to extract the body from the request and the source ip and user agent from the context of the request.

```
{
    "Body": "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.body)",
    "RequestContext" : {
    "Identity" : {
        "SourceIp" : "$context.identity.sourceIp",
        "UserAgent" :  "$context.identity.userAgent"
    },
    "RequestId" : "$context.requestId"
}
```

}

Now, for accessing these values in your lambda, you can do the following:

```
public async Task<SomeResponse> FunctionHandler(APIGatewayProxyRequest gatewayProxyRequest, ILambdaContext context)
    {
        var requestContext = gatewayProxyRequest.RequestContext;
        var sourceIP = requestContext?.Identity?.SourceIp;
        var body = gatewayProxyRequest.Body;
        .
        .
        .
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reference the authorizer lambda's context values in the underlying lambda that's called by the AWS API Gateway, you can use the `RequestContext.Authorizer` as a dictionary, e.g.

```csharp
public async Task<APIGatewayProxyResponse> MyLambaMethodAsync( APIGatewayProxyRequest proxyRequest, ILambdaContext context )
{
    var authorizerContext = proxyRequest.RequestContext.Authorizer;
    var userId = ( (JsonElement)authorizerContext[ "principalId" ] ).GetString();
    var firstName = ( (JsonElement)authorizerContext[ "first_name" ] ).GetString();
    var lastName = ( (JsonElement)authorizerContext[ "last_name" ] ).GetString();
    //... rest of lambda ...
```

Credit to this article for pointing me in the right direction: https://www.rahulpnath.com/blog/aws-dotnet-lambda-authorizer-api-gateway/#pass-custom-data-from-authorizer-to-lambda-function-code